# Jquery/CSS: Force my/at/of position regardless of browser scroll position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, css-position

I've tried to build a simple comments-view using css and jquery, where at the end of each line a "reply" link should pop-up a small box underneath to fill in comments. For this purpose, I use divs which are initially hidden, and which I then show using jquery and which are positioned relative to the link that called them.

This works fine, as long as the browser is in such a scroll-position that the whole form would be visible. However, if there isn't enough space, the form is displayed elsewhere, where it fits. This is even true when I use position:relative in the css: Now, underneath the reply button enough white space will be made available for the form, but the form will still be displayed on top rather than below the button if there isn't enough space.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
#mycomments_list .comment { margin-left: 50px; }
#mycomments_list .form {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background: #248;
padding: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
border-radius: .5em;
-moz-border-radius: .5em;
-webkit-border-radius: .5em;
box-shadow: #000 1px 1px 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: #000 1px 1px 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #000 1px 1px 5px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Jquery:

```
function setCommentFormVisible(id) {
    var item = $("#comment_form_" + id);
    var connector = $(".comment_click#" + id);
    if (!(item.is(":visible"))) {
        item.show();
        item.css({left:0,top:0});
        item.position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "center bottom",
            of: connector });
        connector.addClass("active");
    } else {
        item.hide();
        connector.removeClass("active");
    }
}
```

HTML (excerpt)

```
<div class="comment">
    <div id="1">

    mike --- This is the first comment.. -- 
    <a href="#" class="comment_click" id="1_1">Reply</a> 

    <div class="form" id="comment_form_1_1"> 
        .. form here
    </div>

    </div>

...
</div>
```

I had a vague feeling that this behaviour might be intentional, but then it is quite strange that position:relative would create the space required but then not fill it?

Any pointers at what I might be missing or doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
qz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery UI positioning utility](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) also has a collision parameter. Try setting it to none in your code:

```
function setCommentFormVisible(id) {
    var item = $("#comment_form_" + id);
    var connector = $(".comment_click#" + id);
    if (!(item.is(":visible"))) {
        item.show();
        item.css({left:0,top:0});
        item.position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "center bottom",
            of: connector,
            collision: 'none none' });
        connector.addClass("active");
    } else {
        item.hide();
        connector.removeClass("active");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick! Not quite sure how I managed to miss this :)